# How to handle async task result branches in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

I'm working on an AI system for a game engine. A unit can have an active task that's set by the current unit's AI state. For example, a UnitA can get the task to attack UnitB. The AI state meanwhile has to wait for the task to complete (which can take a few seconds while meanwhile the game loop has to continue).

After the task has been completed the state has to react to the result of the task. For example, if UnitB was killed successfully, the state will continue it's default task (Guard/Stand/Wander depending on the unit). If the task has been interrupted because UnitA is too wounded to continue to attack, the AI state has to be switched to "fleeing".

What approach should I take to most efficiently and as readable as possible do this? Currently I only have tasks implemented with a simple `std::unique_ptr` in the unit of which an Update function gets called. I also have a Move task that sets the task in the unit to nullptr once it's complete but doesn't notify anything else.

I'm looking in the direction of `std::future` using `std::promise` but do not know if there are better ways to do this. There's going to be a lot of active units with AI so I can't spawn a thread to handle the AI state and wait for the `std::future` to give a result, as this will spawn at least over 100 threads at the same time in a decently sized game.

The most important thing I'm looking for in a solution for this is the readability of the branching decision paths the AI will take. I can just make a message queue and make it read results from there with a big switch but that won't clearly show what's happening in what order.

Comment: This is more a conceptual problem than a matter of choosing whatever std:: helpers. What you call a 'task' does not have to map to an actual operating system thread or process. Usually, AI behaviours are implemented as finite state machines running inside a single operating system thread/process. Since basically no I/Os are involved, creating one thread per AI instance would use huge amount or resources for no gain, let alone the unnecessary code complexity.

Comment: I am aware, I was only adding that detail as not being an option though it would indeed have the desired effect of the task branching being represented clearly. The actual state machine for this will handle the higher level states, tasks are here only used as a helper to get a unit to do an action.

Comment: Well future and promise are basically used to synchronize threads, so a single AI thread would have little use of them.

Comment: Look into Boost's state machine libraries: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/?view=category_State